# Problems with cmd.exe and start.batch

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to start  a discord bot but it won't allow me to acess the start.batch file, it just says this. I am currently learning so I dont exactly what it means

I've ran as administrator, not many things I just need some help

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>node bot.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bot.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .`enter code here`
```

I would just like for my bot to work and for it to start because this is the only thing that will allow me to get my bot online.

Thanks

Comment: ...Did you really put your JavaScript file in `system32`? Because that seems unlikely, and that's where your script is looking for it. You likely want to use Command Prompt to navigate to the correct folder.

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>` means that's the folder your console's path is set to. You should set it to the folder in which you've placed `bot.js`. The simplest way to get there is to copy the path from the open folder and paste it in command prompt, prefixed by `cd `. Example: `cd "C:\Projects\My project"`. It works without double quotes if you don't have spaces in the path. (`cd` stands for *change directory*).

Comment: Tried it, still won't open and exits me out when I press a button.

Answer (score 0):

You should change directory to the root folder where your bot.js is located.

Comment: I have multiple times